# Linux urldecode filename

Tags: linux

Is there any tool to urldecode a file's name and replace it?

Example:

```
$ ls
hello%20world.txt
$ urldecode *.txt
$ ls
hello world.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [new blog post](http://blogs.gnome.org/shaunm/2009/12/05/urlencode-and-urldecode-in-sh/) covers this with `echo(1)` and `printf(1)`.

```
urldecode() {
  arg="$1"
  i="0"
  while [ "$i" -lt ${#arg} ]; do
    c0=${arg:$i:1}
    if [ "x$c0" = "x%" ]; then
      c1=${arg:$((i+1)):1}
      c2=${arg:$((i+2)):1}
      printf "\x$c1$c2"
      i=$((i+3))
    else
      echo -n "$c0"
      i=$((i+1))
    fi
  done
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed` and `echo` can urldecode a file's name like so:

```
$ echo -e "$(echo hello%20world+ok | sed 's/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g;s/\\x\(2[Ff]\)/%\1/g')"
hello world ok
```

We want this to be able to turn filenames into filenames,
rather than pathnames (i.e., we don't want to add slashes),
so we leave `%2F` alone. 
(To be more precise, we turn `\x2F` *back* into `%2F`.)

```
$ echo -e "$(echo cat+dog%20foo%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2A%2B%2C%2D%2E%2Fbar |
                                    sed 's/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g;s/\\x\(2[Ff]\)/%\1/g')"
cat dog foo!"#$%&'()*+,-.%2Fbar
```

To actually rename files in the current directory:

```
$ ls *.txt
hello%20%20world++ok?.txt
$ for f in *.txt; do 
>   mv "$f" "$(echo -e "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g;s/\\x\(2[Ff]\)/%\1/g')")"
> done
$ ls *.txt
hello  world  ok?.txt
```

If the original (input) filenames contain backslashes,
they will probably get mangled.

Comment: The idea here is to turn '+'s into spaces directly, and turn % signs into '\x' escapes, and then let echo interpret the \x escapes using the '-e' option. Try running "echo -e 'hello\x20world'" to see this in action.

Comment: How about the part where it renames the file(s)?

Comment: @SamB: left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Seems it doesn't work in all cases, filenames which fails: `10%20-%203%20-%20Model%20Selection%20and%20Train%2FValidation%2FTest%20Sets%20%2812%20min%29.mp410%20-%203%20-%20Model%20Selection%20and%20Train%2FValidation%2FTest%20Sets%20%2812%20min%29.mp4` or `10%20-%205%20-%20Regularization%20and%20Bias%2FVariance%20%2811%20min%29.mp410%20-%205%20-%20Regularization%20and%20Bias%2FVariance%20%2811%20min%29`

Answer (score 1):

I think [this Perl snippet](http://rami.info/2005/11/19/urlencode-and-urldecode-for-perl/) can be used as a base for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Type in shell (or add to .bashrc):

```
urldecode(){
    mv $1 "`echo $1 | xargs python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1])"`"
}
```

Usage:

```
$ urldecode *.txt
```

Tested in bash, zsh. [Credits](https://askubuntu.com/a/53783).