# Can wget decode uri file names when downloading in batch?

Tags: command-line, batch, wget

Normally when downloading files using wget, the filenames are encoded.

In example:

```
wget -c --content-disposition "https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/download.mp4?lecture_id=1"
```

and the saved filename is:

```
13%20-%201%20-%20Unsupervised%20Learning%3A%20Introduction%20%283%20min%29.mp413%20-%201%20-%20Unsupervised%20Learning%3A%20Introduction%20%283%20min%29.mp4
```

Is there any way to decode the files when downloading in batch?

Related:

- [Linux urldecode filename](https://superuser.com/questions/76612/linux-urldecode-filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**deurlname**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/deurlname.1.html)
utility can handle urlencoded filenames.

Comment: if bypassing wget is an option the number of possible answers will increase exponentially :P ..

Comment: `deurlname *.*` works perfect for the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the file name through

```
sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' | xargs echo -e
```